# C++ Error desconocido, no tengo idea que sucede

Tags: c++

El objetivo es formatear la fecha de forma correcta, pero necesito utilizar ese método en el constructor.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "fecha.h"

using namespace std;

    class Fecha
{
    public:
        Fecha();
        Fecha(int a, int b, int c);
        void ImprimirFecha();
        void ImprimirMesLetras();
        int Auxiliar (int days, int ultimo);
        int FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year);

    protected:
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int anio;
};

Fecha::Fecha()
{
    dia=28;
    mes=8;
    anio=2016;
}

Fecha::Fecha(int a, int b, int c)
{
    Fecha::FechaCorrecta(a, b, c);
    dia=a;
    mes=b;
    anio=c;
}

void Fecha::ImprimirFecha()
{
    cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<"/"<<mes<<"/"<<anio<<endl;
}

void Fecha::ImprimirMesLetras()
{
    switch (mes) {
        case 1: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Enero de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 2: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Febrero de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 3: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Marzo de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 4: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Abril de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 5: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Mayo de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 6: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Junio de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 7: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Julio de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 8: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Agosto de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 9: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Septiembre de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 10: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Octubre de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 11: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Novienbre de "<<anio<<endl; break;
        case 12: cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<" de Diciembre de "<<anio<<endl; break;
    }
}

int Auxiliar (int days, int ultimo)
{
    if(days<1 && days>ultimo)
        days=0;

    return days;
}

//declaramos la funcion con sus parametros, la cual sera la encargada de realizar el calculo y regresara el resultado
int FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
    bool bisiesto=false;
    int d=day;
//declaramos d,m,Y para contener los resultados de las operaciones, para que no exista alteraciones. y las inicializamos con los valores enviados para devolverlos mismos en caso de un error.
//En este segmento validamos que el año sea bisiesto cumpliendo que sea multiplo de 4, donde la var bisiesto sera de tipo booleano
    if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
        bisiesto=true;
    else
        bisiesto=false;
//Aca verificamos cuando el mes sea febrero y el año sea bisiesto, manejando el numero de dias para este caso
//"febrero"=29 dias
    if(month==2 && bisiesto==true)
    {
        d=Auxiliar (day, 2);
    }
//Aca verificamos cuando el mes sea febrero y el año No sea bisiesto, manejando el numero de dias para este caso
//"febrero"=28 dias
    if(month==2 && bisiesto==false)
    {
        d=Auxiliar (day, 28);
    }
//Cuando el mes ingresado sea de 30 dias
//"abril","junio","septiembre","noviembre"=30 dias
    if(month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11)
    {
        d=Auxiliar (day, 30);
    }
//Cuando el mes ingresado sea de 31 dias
//"enero","marzo","mayo","julio","agosto","octubre","diciembre"=31 dias
    if(month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month==12)
    {
        d=Auxiliar (day, 31);
    }

//asignamos los resultados que recogieron las varibles d,m,Y y se las asignamos a las varibles enviadas para que retornen el resultado final.

    if(month<1 && month>12)
    {
        day=0;
        month=0;
    }

    if(year<1)
    {
        day=0;
        month=0;
        year=0;
    }

    day=d;
    return 0;
}

main() {
    //declaramos la clase que contruimos para calcular el area de la superficie y las varibles a utilizar
    int d=0, m=0, y=0;
    int opcion=0;
    char continuar=0, salir=0;
    //imprimimos informacion y luego cactamos los datos para el calculo 
    cout<<" Aplicacion para Registrar la fecha de entrada"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Ingresar fecha de entrada. Introduzca el dia/mes/a#o: "<<endl;
        cin>>d>>m>>y;
        Fecha day(d,m,y);
        system("cls");
        cout<<"----------------------Menus------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.-Imprimir fecha registrada dia/mes/a#0."<<endl;
        cout<<"2.-Imprimir fecha con el mes en palabras."<<endl;
        cout<<"3.-Modificar fecha registrada."<<endl;
        cout<<"4.-Salir."<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        //imprimimos
        do
        {
            cout<<"Elegir una opcion para continuar: ";
            cin>>opcion;
            salir='n';

            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    day.ImprimirFecha();
                    continuar='s';
                break;
                case 2:
                    day.ImprimirMesLetras();
                    continuar='s';
                break;
                case 3:
                    continuar='n';
                    salir='s';
                break;
                case 4:
                    cout<<"Si continuar salir presione la tecla 'S' sino 'N': ";
                    cin>>continuar;
                    salir='n';
                break;
            }

        }
        while(continuar=='s');

    }
    while(salir=='s');

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenos días @Mario. Te recomendaría editar tu pregunta y añadir el código directamente en la misma. La pregunta puede residir en este foro por muchos años y si el enlace deja de estar disponible entonces ya no será de utilidad para nadie. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por responder. es mi primer post. saludos

Comment: Un consejo: Para añadir código fíjate que el mismo aparece indentado con 4 espacios... también puedes seleccionar el fragmento de código y presionar el botón con dos llaves "{}" para que el editor formatee esa sección y el código pueda verse correctamente.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Fecha
{
    public:
        int FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year);
};

Fecha::Fecha(int a, int b, int c)
{
    Fecha::FechaCorrecta(a,b,c);
}
```

Las llamadas tipo `Clase::Funcion()` se usan para funciones estáticas y para llamar a funciones de la clase padre ocultas por la implementación de la clase hija (que no es tu caso). El problema en tu caso es que la función `FechaCorrecta` no está declarada como estática. Por legibilidad deberías aplicar una de estas dos opciones:

1. Declara la función como estática
2. Elimina el prefijo de la clase en la llamada a la función:

Dicho con código:

```
// Opción 1
class Fecha
{
    public:
        static int FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year);
};

// Opción 2
Fecha::Fecha(int a, int b, int c)
{
    FechaCorrecta(a,b,c);
}
```

En cuanto a tu error: Fíjate en la implementación de `FechaCorrecta` y en la implementación de `ImprimirFecha`:

```
void Fecha::ImprimirFecha()
{
    cout<<"Fecha Registrada: "<<dia<<"/"<<mes<<"/"<<anio<<endl;
}

int FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
}
```

La diferencia es evidente. En `FechaCorrecta` te falta incluir el prefijo de la clase para indicar que esa implementación se corresponde con la función definida dentro de la clase `Fecha`:

```
int Fecha::FechaCorrecta (int &day, int &month, int &year)
{
}
```

Y lo mismo te sucede con la función `Auxiliar`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta podrias revisar de nuevo, como esta haciendo pruebas antes de formular la pregunta, como deberia ir

Comment: Porque lo que busco lograr, es cuando haga la instancia del objeto con el constructor con parametros el metodo fechacorrecta me devuelva por referencia los valores y las variables dia,mes,anio me quden instanciadas con los valores referenciados

Comment: si el error estaba en que le faltaba el prefijo. mas de 4 horas buscando el error. y no podia ver esa pequeña falla. ya se me hacia imposible intertar de otra forma. muchas gracias

Comment: @MarioP si tienes nuevas preguntas sobre algo lo mejor es que formules una pregunta nueva. La pregunta presente trata sobre el error que encuentras en tu código no sobre devolver variables por referencia.